# Why do notes have stems?

Tags: theory, notation, history

How is it that stems became a part of standard music notation?

I was genuinely unable to find an answer to this anywhere on the internet - I couldn't even find an instance of anyone asking the question.

Comment: Both the breve and the semi-breve do not have stems.

Comment: How else would one signify notes shorter than crotchets - with tails on the stems?

Comment: "the definitive origin and reasoning behind note stems": stems have been used for different purposes at different times.  Are you interested in any appearance of stems or in the first example where they are clearly used to encode rhythmic information?

Answer (score 4):

According to Apel's book on chant, the earliest Gregorian Chant notation had lots of marks (so the TRVE ORIGIN is probably lost in historical obscurity); there were two single note marks, one sort of like a dash or a dot (called a punctum) and one like a tail-walking tadpole (called a virga.) The punctum represented a low tone or a tone reached by descending; the virga represented a high tone or a tone reached by ascending. This was before the staff (of 1 to 7 or more lines) was introduced. Other single-note signs developed from these.

Answer (score 2):

**Current meaning**

With the style of note heads and other signs, note stem (along its flag which is attached to the stem) is a way to show the length of a note in Western style of writing music (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_value)):

- no stem means is a whole note (usually 4 beats)
- stem without flag means half-note (usually 2 beats) if the note is hollow, quarter-note if the note is filled black (usually 1 beat)
- stem with single flag means eighth note (usually half a beat)
- stem with double flags means sixteenth note (usually quarter a beat)
- stem with triple flags means thirty-second note (usually eighth a beat)
- etc

**Early appearance of stems**

Earliest stems may have appeared with earliest [neumes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neume) in Gregorian singing (~9th-11th centuries), but their roles are not related to note length.[image]

**Early use of stems for note duration**

In the 12th-13th century, it may be [Pérotin and his students](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9rotin#Life,_and_problems_of_identification) who first used the stems as temporal signs (along with the note shape), with the introduction of proportional duration, which divided the time unit (maxime) into longa, brevis et semi-brevis .

[image]

**When did current style of stems appear?**

The current style of stems may have been fixed later with standardization of music notation constrained by the use of print characters (however, alternative notations are still in use, e.g.[shape notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shape_note)). I'm missing documentation to tell more about this.

Comment: The use of note stems to convey rhythmic information predates printing by several centuries.

Comment: Thanks @phoog, I modified the last paragraph to make it clearer, and I added a paragraph about Pérotin for a maybe-first use of stem for note duration